# ScrollBy() is not working

Tags: android, scrollview

As the title

I have a fragment layout like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/host_profile_scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >
</Scrollview>
```

declare my Scrolview:

```
 content = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.host_profile_scroll_view);
```

and then I set on click listener for a button

```
public void onClick(View v) {
content.scrollBy(0, +20);
System.out.println(content.canScrollVertically(+20));
}
```

But It not working at all and the sysout comman always print out "false".
My question is what cause canScrollVertically get false result and how to resolved is .
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Is the content of scrollview scrollable? I mean for the code you wrote, the content of the scrollview should have height at least 20px greater than the height of scrollview.

Comment: height of the content is greater than 20px for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In fact , the method 'scrollBy' move the content of ViewGroup . Here, if you want to move the ScrollView ,you should call the scrollBy of its father View .